# Swift 4 custom generic struct with optional array behaves strange?

Tags: swift, generics, swift4

I'm migrating a larger codebase to Swift 4. It includes a custom type that implements a matrix. In Swift 3.1 everything works well and as expected.

I was able to reduce the problem to two small code blocks. The first one defines the struct:

```
struct Matrix<Element> {
    var array:[Element?] = []

    mutating func setup(repeatedValue:Element) {
        let fooTemp = Array<Element?>(repeating: repeatedValue, count: 10)
        self.array = fooTemp
    }
}
```

The problem itself comes when I add the `Sequence` implementation:

```
extension Matrix: Sequence {
    typealias Iterator = AnyIterator<Element?>

    func makeIterator() -> Iterator {
        return AnyIterator(array.makeIterator())
    }
}
```

As soon as the `Sequence` implementation is part of the code, I get a compiler error in the line `self.array = fooTemp`:

> Cannot assign value of type '[Element??]' to type '[_?]'

I know, that I can fix this issue by using `let fooTemp = Array<Element>` in the code. The type inference does not respect this and make fooTemp an `Array<Element?>`.

**What's going on here? Compiler shenanigans?**

The issue occurs in Swift 3.2 as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Sequence` protocol defines

```
/// A type that provides the sequence's iteration interface and
/// encapsulates its iteration state.
associatedtype Element where Self.Element == Self.Iterator.Element
```

and that causes a conflict, since your `Self.Iterator.Element` is
`Element?`. Choosing a different name for your generic placeholder
solves the problem.